# Why is SPWeb.ID empty?

Tags: api, sharepoint

I want to get the GUID for a particular SPWEB.
But when I try to check the value of SPWEB.ID, it is empty.

My code:

```
**Using blogSiteSPWeb As SPWeb = siteCollectSPSite.OpenWeb(returnedSearchPath(pathCount))**

   **For Each subsite As SPWeb In blogSiteSPWeb.Webs

 dim guid as GUID

      guid = subsite.ID 

   .......
   Next

end using**
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work to get the current web context:

```
string _siteURL =  SPContext.Current.Site.Url;

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(_siteURL)
{
  {
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      ... some code here
  }
}
```

Now web.ID will be set to the URL of the current site